# How to update custom Drawable with Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

How to redraw already created Drawable using Bitmap without to create new Drawable?

Usage:

```
Drawable drawable = new MyDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
makeSomeAsyncOperation((newBitmap) -> drawable.setBitmap(newBitmap));
```

MyDrawable.java:

```
class MyDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    public void setBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

Here is some specific implementation and other ways doesn't suitable.